# Disaster Recovery Site with DC's from two sites

Tags: active-directory

SiteA = primary 
SiteB = DR 
Can I have two DC's in the DR location, but have one in SiteA and one in SiteB, but both on the same network? Each site has it's own subnets.  I could add the /32 (part of SiteB's subnet) of the SiteA DC to the SiteA subnets. 
This is all to make it possible to make when SiteA dies, I make the SiteA subnets live in the DR location and turn replicated systems on while still keeping the AD structure together in a disaster.  SiteB has it's own systems always running so combining all into one site isn't an option I want to really entertain.

Comment: This really doesn't make sense. What woulds this accomplish? Why do you need Site A subnets to "live" at Site B if Site A fails? Let AD do what it does. What is it that you think will happen if Site A fails that will "undo" the AD structure?

Comment: DR site, Site A disappears, i turn all systems on from SiteA in SiteB after adding the network in this location, many VM's that are part of SiteA and SiteA's subnets that are configured.

Comment: Then just re-associate the Site A subnets to Site B in ADS&S in that scenario.